# Are there any obvious performance issues of mass-using SKActions?

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

I have a game where I use a lot of SKActions to deliver the desired game logic.

For example, instead of setting the `zRotation` of a sprite to a value, I would use `runAction(SKAction.rotateTo(/* angle here */, duration: 0.0)` instead.

I make calls like this in `update`, and in `touchesMoved`. Thus this could mean hundreds of these calls, sometimes nested with groups of other actions.

Am I incurring significant overhead relative to directly setting the `zRotation` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use SKActions for real-time motion. Instead you should either set the zRotation directly or set the necessary angular velocity each frame. In your case the update method and touchesMoved method are both bad to use for SKActions because they can run 30-60 times a second.

SKActions do generate significant overhead. Here is a quote from Apple's documentation:

> ### When You Shouldn’t Use Actions
>
> Although actions are efficient, there
>   is a cost to creating and executing them. If you are making changes to
>   a node’s properties in every frame of animation and those changes need
>   to be recomputed in each frame, you are better off making the changes
>   to the node directly and not using actions to do so. For more
>   information on where you might do this in your game, see Advanced
>   Scene Processing.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH11-SW28)

You can see an example of using real-time motion instead of SKActions in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29443170/2158465)

Answer (score 2):

You should not call a SKAction in the update method as it is called 60 times a second. Instead, use a event based trigger which in turn calls the SKAction. The touchesMoved is a good example of that. You can also use a completion method block to signal for a new SKAction upon completion of the current action.